# How can i delete shipping and billing addreses from reports

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I work with Odoo 9 
How can i delete shipping and billing addreses from reports ?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: odoo consist of so many reports, in which report you want to delete, explain your working trails.

Comment: in Quote, order form, delivery, invoice

Answer (score 1):

```
<openerp>
<data>
    <template id="sale_quotation_override" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
        <xpath expr="//t[@t-call='report.external_layout']" position="replace">
            <!-- your custom code here..... -->
        </xpath>
    <template>
<data>
```

inside xpath what ever you write that will be printed in report. xpath **position="replace"** override the previous code of sale qutation, 
here are the links [custom creation report](http://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/creating-custom-reports-odoo-8/),[reports inheriting](http://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/inheriting-and-modifying-qweb-reports/).
if you want to change main code then just comment out `<div class="row">` tag inside code it won't display on the report.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to remove those details from Sale Order Report.

For this you can inherit the sale order report and then either customise it fully as per your need or use xpath as per conditions.

Sample -

```
<report id="sale.sale_order_report_id">
.
.
. Your custom report code here.
.
</report>
```